# Previewing php pages inside Expression Web 3 suddently stopped working

Tags: php, iis, expression-web

On a Windows 7 development machine, I have expression web 3, PHP 5 installed

I have been using expression web and PHP for a while, and previewing php pages etc on pressing F12 (preview using local server). Suddenly on F12 all PHP pages display as blank, even a `phpinfo()` file. Standard html pages continue to work correctly on F12.

If I place the same page php inside the default website on `inetpub` and browse using localhost then the `phpinfo()` file works.  So I know that php is installed and configured correctly for IIS.

Things I've checked:

- Gone into site settings in Expression web and confirmed that php is selected and it is pointing to the php executable
- Reinstalled php
- Checked iis that the php extension is registered.
- Copied files to a different machine with expression web and php installed and it works on.
- The strange thing is that it gives a blank (no errors) page inside expression web, but does work inside inetpub
- This was working up until recently, then suddenly stopped for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution to my particular problem.

The php.ini file had been edited but something was wrong with the format that it was saved in.  Deleting the php.ini and getting a new one brought php back to life.

Strange to note that NO error was reported at all to give any indication as to why it wasn't working.